# change label text in widgets created in loop dynamically from a dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

Im working on a tkinter GUI that creates labels from a dictionary.
on of the labels is a "Fails" counter (theres another function that updates this value in the dictionary) id like if so when the "fails" is updated in the dictionary, it updates the fails value in the label.

heres a snippet if createing the labels from the dictionary. i cant figure out how to make it so the fails_label text is changed when the dictionary is updated

Thank you

```
        row = 2
        widgets = {}
        for key in obj2create:

            strEngNumber = obj2create[key][0]
            strLayer = obj2create[key][1]
            strFile = obj2create[key][2]
            intFails = obj2create[key][3] 

            
            strJobKey = key

            job_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=key, anchor="w",
                                  justify="center", wraplength=701,background=bg)
            job_label.grid(row=row, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, ipady=3)

            eng_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=strEngNumber, anchor="w",
                                  justify="center", wraplength=701,background=bg)
            eng_label.grid(row=row, column=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
            
            layer_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=strLayer, anchor="w",
                                  justify="center", wraplength=701,background=bg)
            layer_label.grid(row=row, column=2, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
            
            file_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=strFile, anchor="w",
                                  justify="center", wraplength=701,background=bg)
            file_label.grid(row=row, column=3, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")

            fails_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=intFails, anchor="w",
                                  justify="center", wraplength=701,background=bg)
            fails_label.grid(row=row, column=4, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="w")
```

Comment: You can create a class inherited from `dict` and override the class function `__setitem__()`.  Inside the class function, you can do whatever you want.  Then make `obj2create` an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trace_add()` method like in the example below:

```
from tkinter import *

def update(var, index, mode):
    label.configure(text=intFails.get())

def functionOnClick():
    intFails.set(intFails.get() + 1)

w = Tk()
w.geometry('400x400')

intFails = IntVar(w, 0)
intFails.trace_add('write', update)

label = Label(w, textvariable=intFails, anchor="w", justify="center", font=('Arial', 22))
label.place(x=0, y=0)

btn = Button(w, text='Click', command=functionOnClick, font=('Arial', 22))
btn.place(x=0, y=80, width = 100, height = 80)

w.mainloop()
```

This method helps you to automatically detect, when variable was changed. Though it works only with special `IntVar()` and `StringVar()`, but I think it's only possible way to do this at least with this type of vars.

On the other hand, you can try to create a class with dictionary as your field and works with it by `set property`. This [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) may be useful for you.